# Can I use ManualResetEvent across assemblies?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm still in the planning stages so I don't have full code to show. But I was curious as to how the manualresetevent would be used if you want to synchronize threads between different assemblies. For example, I have written classA in assembly1 that performs task1(). Next, I have another classB in Assembly2 where I create a thread to run classA.task1(). I would like to for classB to wait until classA is done. It is important (let's just assume) that I run this on a separate thread. In short, a snippet of code will look like:

Assembly2.ClassB:

```
private void main() { // for brevity
   Thread newThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(assembly1.classA.task));
   newThread.Start();
   // Wait until some process in classA.task() is done

   if(classA.mySocket.Connected) {
        // this may never occur because task1() didn't complete it's job
   }

   // do the rest
}
```

Assembly1.ClassA

```
public Socket mySocket;

public void task1() {
   // must stop all other threads until these lines have
   // been processed

   // create socket, and connect to remote endpoint

   // Ok, to signal other threads to continue.
   startReceiving();
}

private void startReceiving() {
   while(IsValid) {
       mySocket.Receive(); //
   }
}
```

Do I need to create ManualResetEvents on both classes? How can this work?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I've updated the code for a more valid example, please don't mind the syntax, I'm just trying to get the idea across.

Comment: You should only need to create one manual reset event in b. Call task1 on a new thread and wait till it finishes

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is fine, but you need to share the instance of `ManualResetEvent` across the two objects. You can pass this shared instance in via the constructor on `Thread` that takes a `ParameterizedThreadStart`.

But if all you're doing is waiting until `newThread` is done, just use [`Thread.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta.aspx):

```
newThread.Start();
newThread.Join();
```

Comment: I may try the ParameterizedThreadStart. As I commented to dtb, this new thread may last a very long time before it completes since there are only a few lines of code I'm trying to protect within the same routine.

Answer (score 2):

The code in `Assembly1.ClassA` doesn't know that it's called in a separate thread from `Assembly2.ClassB`, so I'd consider it bad style to introduce a mechanism where `Assembly1.ClassA.task1` signals that it's done.

For your scenario, it looks like you just need to call [Thread.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta.aspx):

> **Thread.Join Method**
>
> Blocks the calling thread until a thread terminates

*Example:*

```
private void Main()
{
   Thread newThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Assembly1.ClassA.Task1));

   // Start thread
   newThread.Start();

   // Wait until the invoked method returns
   newThread.Join();

   // Do the rest
   ...
}
```

Note that this is just the same as

```
private void Main()
{
   // Invoke method and wait until invoked method returns
   Assembly1.ClassA.Task1();

   // Do the rest
   ...
}
```

So I guess I don't understand your question.

---

Based on your updated question, I'd say that `Assembly1.ClassA` should be the one resposible for spinning up the thread:

```
public class ClassA
{
    private Socket socket;
    private Thread thread;

    public void Connect()
    {
        socket = new Socket(...);
        socket.Connect(...);

        thread = new Thread(DoWork);
        thread.Start();
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        socket.Close();

        thread.Join();
    }

    private void DoWork()
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                int received = socket.Receive(buffer, ...);
                if (received == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
                // process buffer
                ...
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I need to keep the thread alive? In other words, in the code snippet, only a few lines are required that all threads are to stop. After that, the new thread could last a while, that would certainly block the calling thread, right?

Comment: @Ed Gl: Can you expand on what these few special lines do? Could a `lock` be more appropriate than a signal?